# Why must the beta term in the rigid-rotator PDE take the form J(J+1)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy

Here is the partial differential equation for which the solutions Y are are the wave functions for the rigid-rotator (Equation 5.5 in McQuarrie and Simon's Physical Chemistry).

$$\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial Y}{\partial \theta}\right) + \frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial \phi^2} + \left(\beta \sin^2\theta\right)Y = 0$$

In McQuarrie and Simon's Physical Chemistry, it is said that

> When we solve Equation 5.5, it turns out naturally that $\beta$ ... must obey the condition: $$\beta = J(J+1)$$

My question is ***why must $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ take the form $\boldsymbol{J(J+1)}$ (where $\boldsymbol{J}$ is a natural number))?*** Since $\beta$ is essentially a constant, this implies that using any value of $\beta$ (e.g., 1.5) would lead to a partial differential equation with no solutions. (1) is this assumption correct and (2) if so, what is the mathematical proof that $\beta$ in any other form would lead to no solutions?

Comment: $\beta$ must take this form because any other value of $\beta$ would lead to a partial differential equation with no ***nice*** solutions. As for the mathematical proof, it can be neither told nor heard without doing quite a bit of math.

Comment: I guess, in the linked question I only explicitly show that the term must be of the form J(J+1), and I don't actually prove that J must be a non-negative integer (assuming that we're talking only about orbital angular momentum). As Ivan's comment notes, the proof of *that* is pretty ugly (you must explicitly solve the differential equations), and you are best served by looking it up in a textbook of your choice. I think the solutions are called associated Legendre polynomials, so that will give you a search term. Btw, if you look it up, skip the chemistry books—go straight to physics or maths.